# How to convert numpy array to string and vice versa

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

The following code is trying to convert the `image` array to `string`, and then regenerate the `image` from `string`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = np.ones((28,28))
print("image: {}".format(image.shape))

string = "{}".format(image.tostring())
print("len: {}".format(len(string)))

string_to_image = np.fromstring(string)
print("string_to_image: {}".format(string_to_image.shape))
```

**Here is the output:**

```
image: (28, 28)
len: 22739

/tmp/ipykernel_2794/3542140279.py:7: DeprecationWarning: tostring() is deprecated. Use tobytes() instead.
  string = "{}".format(image.tostring())
/tmp/ipykernel_2794/3542140279.py:10: DeprecationWarning: The binary mode of fromstring is deprecated, as it behaves surprisingly on unicode inputs. Use frombuffer instead
  string_to_image = np.fromstring(string)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_2794/3542140279.py in <cell line: 10>()
      8 print("len: {}".format(len(string)))
      9 
---> 10 string_to_image = np.fromstring(string)
     11 print("string_to_image: {}".format(string_to_image.shape))

ValueError: string size must be a multiple of element size
```

How to fix the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Below code, need to use right datatype **dtype=np.uint8**

```
string_to_image = np.fromstring(string, dtype=np.uint8)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright so the first problem is the `DeprecationWarning`. With `Python 3.2` and onwards, `.tostring()` and `.fromstring` have been replaced with `.tobytes()` and `.frombuffer()`. They are functionally the same, so you don't lose anything from using them, however for `.frombuffer()` to work properly we need to make sure we pass a bytes-like object so I removed the `"{}".format()` part.

The next problem is the shape. When you convert a numpy array to a string (or bytes-like object) it loses it's shape, however we cans imply fix this but using the `.reshape()` method.

And that's it, the code with all the changes is below and it should work as intended:)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = np.ones((28,28))
print("image: {}".format(image.shape))

string = image.tobytes()
print("len: {}".format(str(string)))

string_to_image = np.frombuffer(string, dtype=int).reshape((28,28))
print("string_to_image: {}".format(string_to_image.shape))
```

Comment: The string in your code is a type of "bytes", my question is for converting it to "string" and then get the image from "string", not from bytes.